# Python is not Recognizing All of my Command Line Arguments

Tags: python, bash, command-line-arguments

I don't know if this is just a newbie mistake, but Python is not recognizing all of my arguments. I am using bash, so maybe this is the problem. I have a working argument called -vs and I am trying to make it detect a necessary integer after it, so the appropriate syntax is `program.py -vs 5`, or some integer. However, it does not recognize the "5". It does when I put the dash (-) next to it and make it start with a letter. How can I get Python to see this?

Here's a fragment of the code:

```
elif arg == "-vs" or "--vertical-spacing":
        if int(sys.argv[argnum + 1]) >= 0:
            vspacing = int(sys.argv[argnum + 1])
        else:
            print "Invalid Spacing: Less than zero (Ya can't have negative spacing, silly!)"

            sys.exit()
```

By the way, the argnum variable increases by one every time as I loop through these arguments. (I'm using a `for arg in sys.argv[1:]`. Do not worry, I start argnum as 0 and incrementing it is the first thing I do when looping, so it does not see the program path and/or name, or `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: Can you please post the part of your python code that parses the command line args?

Comment: Sure, let me modify my post.

Comment: Done, refresh the page, I added my code and a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Also have you considered using a standard argument parsing library like `argparse`, which will handle many edge cases for you https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html ?

Comment: I may consider this, it seems much easier, although the standard library is pretty easy to get the hang of. If it does hand this sort of thing, it won't be hard to replace the standard calls. I will review this, thanks!

Comment: Your description could use clarification. First, how about a real working example. It should only be a dozen lines. What do you mean by "it does not recognize the 5"? Maybe a print in that if/else would help. _"(I'm using a for arg in f, with f being the file object)"_ - um, what? We are talking command line, right? what file? Why don't these names match the example?

Comment: Ooh nice, it's in the standard libraries.

Comment: @jadenPete, I added an example for your use case with `argparse`

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it enough for you. When I say it doesn't recognize the 5, I mean it is completely not present in the sys.argv list. Sorry my brain isn't working today, I meant sys.argv[1:] instead of f (i'm making an interpreter). Getting the line looping and argument looping mixed up xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with argparse instead:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-vs", "--vertical-spacing", type=int, dest="vertical_spacing", help="vertical spacing. must be > 0")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not args.vertical_spacing:
      print "Invalid Spacing: Less than zero (Ya can't have negative spacing, silly!)"
      sys.exit()

    some_function(args.vertical_spacing)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, this will make it much easier to implement this, instead of reading a million manual pages.